# R coord_map versus coord_proj proj4 with ortho projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, proj

In an attempt to reproduce

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_African_Republic#/media/File:Central_African_Republic_-_Location_Map_(2013)_-*CAF*-_UNOCHA.svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_African_Republic#/media/File:Central_African_Republic_-_Location_Map_(2013)_-_CAF_-_UNOCHA.svg)

My first challenge is to reproduce the orthogonal projection without artifacts:

```
library(rworldmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
map.world <- map_data(map="world")
gg <- ggplot() +
  geom_cartogram(aes(long, lat, map_id = region), data=map.world, map=map.world) 
gg + coord_map("ortho", orientation = c(4.22, 18.35, 0))+theme_map()
```

`coord_map` returns some artifacts in the shapefiles near the edge of the sphere (e.g. China. (straight lines instead of arcs)

Can this be solved by using proj4, `coord_proj`?

Is there a way to give the globe/oceans a background colour?

Comment: (clarifying q) so, you're looking to replicate that chart as closely as possible?

Comment: as a starting point, yes. It looks like a nice challenge (also as the inset is a sphere). For colouring the globe I am looking into https://github.com/ropenscilabs/rnaturalearth with the ocean50 data